# Cakephp: How to get rid of an unwated join?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

[image]

I want to get rid of CategoriesRecord Array. 
I bind the models using:

```
$this->Category->bindModel(
                array('hasAndBelongsToMany' =>
                    array(
                        'Record' =>
                        array(
                            'className' => 'Record',
                            //'joinTable' => 'categories_records',
                            'foreignKey' => 'categories_id',
                            'associationForeignKey' => 'records_id',
                            'conditions' => array('Record.active' => 1)
                        )
                    )
                )
        );
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Habtm requires an intermediate table - that is the joinTable in the relationship you commented out. By default this will use an instance of the AppModel called CategoriesRecord which maps to the categories_records table.

You can't get rid of this intermediate model / table or habtm won't work. (It is the "join table" for the many to many relationship)

There really isn't any harm in keeping the array in the returned data - it actually gives you a convenient way to access each of the related id values when building forms / action links etc.

Comment: If it is really an issue returning too much data - you can always use the afterFind callback to loop over your results and unset the array. -- Or you can use the Set class to extract out just what you need before passing it to the view. Again, without that intermediate table you would have no many to many relationship. Once you fetch the data though, you should be fine to remove that index from each of the results (especially if you don't need the know which 2 related id's are involved anywhere in the view)

Answer (score 1):

try containable behaviour to get rid of things you don't need. Use it when you use find();
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Comment: Thx for the answer - I use Containable but I really can't get rid of the array - I suppose Abba Bryant is right - otherwise prove I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

As jacktrade told [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) behavior is the best solution if you have lots of tables and relations.Even though you can try [BindModel and Unbind Model](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly) on the fly.

```
$this->Model->unbindModel(
    array('associationType' => array('associatedModelClassName'))
);
```